# How can I save my data from wordpress form submissions to a json file

Tags: json, wordpress, forms, amazon-web-services

I have created a form on AWS Wordpress using NinjaForms and want to save this data to a JSON file. The form is working properly. Is there any plugin that could help me with this?

If you could redirect me to any tutorial about this stuff would be fine too. Honestly, I am very new to wordpress and I apologize if this is a very basic question.

Any inputs are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer

You need to use a hook from ninja forms first
Then go to function.php of your theme and access $form_data at the hook function and extract and save the data yourself.

This is pretty much how anyone would go about to send a POST request to an API from your form